# Does resetting user password from root cause any file problems?

Tags: hard-drive, password, root

When i reset the password on my HDD in root (shell) whilst in recovery mode, does it lead to all data being deleted on this HDD? I heard this somewhere, and i sincerely hope its not true, because i would be screwed if it were :/

Comment: It doesn't delete data but if encrypted you won't be able to access it after changing the password.

Comment: Okay. "Wont be able to access"...like, in will never ever be able to access it again? Or can i somehow "unencrypt" the hdd, since i also have the old passphrase available?

Comment: I don't use encryption, I'm not the one to answer that, but I suppose you can by using the proper tools.

Comment: Do you use full disk encryption with LUKS? If you're asked for a passphrase before login, this is the case. This is totally independent of the user management, and will not be touched by a password reset. If you however use ubuntus encrypted home directories, I'm not certain.

Comment: I am not certain. Probably only the decrypted home directories, since it doenst ask for any passphrase when booting. However i have a passphrase written down, so it will probably be relevant in some way in undoing the encryption somehow.

Comment: Change the password back to what it was